# Postgres database column defaults with ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use UUIDs as my default key in ruby on rails with a postgres db and I would like Postgres to generate the keys.  What is the RoR way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
create_table(:deals, :id => false) do |t|
  t.uuid :uuid, :null => false
  t.integer :quantity
  t.timestamps
end

add_index(:deals, :uuid, :unique => true, :name => 'deals_pkey')
```